# Need help to increment by 1 using a for loop. Only increment by 1 each time

Tags: c#, for-loop, increment

So I have a Score Method, which is run after we play, and again if the user wants to replay the game. I am showing scores in it.

Such as

First Try :

```
Game 1 : He scored 20
```

then the user decides to replay the game, gets a different score. Then I want it to show.

Second Try :

```
Game 1 : He scored 20

Game 2 : He scored 10
```

Third Try : etc

```
Game 1 : He Scored 20

Game 2 : He scored 10

Game 3 : He scored 5
```

I have tried using a for loop inside a foreach, then putting the i into another int

```
public void HighScore()
        {
            int gameList = 1;
            foreach (var item in Points)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < Points.Count; i++)
                {
                    gameList = i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"{name} : Game {gameList} Score : {item} : Level [{GameLevel}]");
            }
        }
```

//Points is a Int List

//I want to change the game numbers Game 1, 2, 3, 4,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a `for` loop:

```
public void HighScore()
    {
        int gameList = 1;
        foreach (var item in Points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} : Game {gameList} Score : {item} : Level [{GameLevel}]");
            gameList++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// use like this 
gameList++;

// instead of doing this
gameList = i++;
```

I hope now you will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Fristly you dont need a for loop.Create a class for accessing point for every game for store them regularly like above.

```
    public class Score
    {
        public Score(int point ,int game)
        {
            Point = point;
            Game = game;
        }

        public int Point { get; set; }
        public int Game { get; set; }


    }
```

And then create a global variable

```
List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();
```

so you can save your score and gameCount.

```
    int point = 10;//any number
    int lastGame = (scores.Any()) ? scores.Last().Game : 0;//this is about first game if no score its first game
    scores.Add(new Score(point, lastGame += 1));
```

you can show to user confortable with loop.

```
foreach(var score in scores){
Console.WriteLine($"Game {score.Game} Point: {score.Point}");

}
    Game  Score
     1      10
     2      20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

Use `gameList++` instead of `gameList = i++;`  [Unary Increment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-)

```
public static void HighScore()
{
    int gameList = 1;
    List<int> Points = new List<int>() { 10,20,39,40,50};

    foreach (var item in Points)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Game {gameList} Score : {item}");

        gameList++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: Did u get an error? Obviously output wont be same but it is 'Unary increment operator '++' is what he is looking for.

Comment: You are adding the *length* of the list to the game number each time, so the games are numbered 5, 9, 13, etc. I think the OP wanted 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @iakobski well spotted. Thanks. Updated my answer.